# Oracle analytical function with group by

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Normally we are doing group by dept_name and find max and min salary.

```
select dept_name,sum(salary),max(salary).min(salary) from emp group by dept_name;
```

But how can i find the name of employee(s) who is getting max salary and min salary. Is it possible to find in single sql statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) function:

```
SELECT dept_name, SUM(salary), MAX(salary), MIN(salary),
    MAX(emp_name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY salary) AS Min_salary_emp,
    MAX(emp_name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY salary) as  Max_salary_emp 
FROM emp 
GROUP BY dept_name;
```

Note, if you have more than one employee with the same salary, you get only one of them.

Depending on your requirements you could also use [Pattern Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm)

```
SELECT dept_name, MAX_salary, MIN_salary, salary, emp_name,
    Min_salary_emp, Max_salary_emp
FROM emp
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY dept_name
    ORDER BY salary
    MEASURES 
        FINAL MIN(salary) AS MIN_salary,
        FINAL MAX(salary) AS MAX_salary,
        a.emp_name AS Min_salary_emp,
        c.emp_name AS Max_salary_emp
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN ( (a+ {- b* -} c+) | a )
    DEFINE
    a AS salary = MIN(salary),
    c AS salary = MAX(salary)
);
```

Comment: @Wernfired Domscheit : Perfect.. thanks a lot.. working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of subquery :

```
select emp_name from employee where salary = (select max(salary) from employee) 
or salary = (select min(salary) from employee) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
WITH cteDepts as (select dept_name,
                         sum(salary) AS TOTAL_SALARY,
                         max(salary) AS MIN_SALARY,
                         min(salary) AS MAX_SALARY
                    from emp
                    group by dept_name)
SELECT d.*, emin.EMP_NAME, emax.EMP_NAME
  FROM cteDepts d
  INNER JOIN EMP emin
    ON emin.SALARY = d.MIN_SALARY
  INNER JOIN EMP emax
    ON emax.SALARY = d.MAX_SALARY
```

I don't know what the employee name column is in your EMP table so I've used `EMP_NAME`. If the column name is different than that you'll need to change the query to use the correct column name.

Best of luck.